# Combining React videojs component's state with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am currently having a videojs component (with markers) in my react application. I want to move to react-redux. I am trying to store the state of this component in a reducer. But I am not able to figure out the correct way. Her is my code.

```
import assign from 'object-assign'
import cx from 'classnames'
import blacklist from 'blacklist'
import React, {Component} from 'react'


export default class PlayerLogic extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            player : {}
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        var self = this;
        var player = videojs(this.refs.video, this.props.options).ready(function () {
            self.player = this;
            self.player.on('play', self.handlePlay);
        });

        if (this.props.onPlayerInit) this.props.onPlayerInit(player);
         player.markers({
            markerStyle: {},
            markers: [
                {length: 8, startTime: 10, endTime: 15, time: 9.5, text: "Cigarette"},
                {length: 2, startTime: 20, endTime: 25, time: 16, text: "Cigarette"},

            ],
            onMarkerReached: function () {
                player.pause();
            },

            next : function() {
                // go to the next marker from current timestamp
                console.log("reached");
                var currentTime = player.currentTime();
                for (var i = 0; i < markersList.length; i++) {
                    var markerTime = setting.markerTip.time(markersList[i]);
                    if (markerTime > currentTime) {
                        player.currentTime(markerTime);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            },


        });

        this.setState({ player: player });
        console.log({player: player});
    }

    next() {
        this.state.player.markers.next();
    }
    prev() {
        this.state.player.markers.prev();
    }

    handlePlay(){
        console.log("handle play ")
    }

    render() {
        var props = blacklist(this.props, 'children', 'className', 'src', 'type', 'onPlay');
        props.className = cx(this.props.className, 'videojs', 'video-js vjs-default-skin', 'vjs-big-play-centered');

        assign(props, {
            ref: 'video',
            controls: true,
            width: "700", height: "450"
        });


        return (
            <div>
                <video {... props}>
                    <source src={this.props.src} type={this.props.type} id={this.props.id}/>
                </video>
                <button onClick={this.next.bind(this)}>next</button>
                <button onClick={this.prev.bind(this)}>prev</button>
            </div>)

    }
}
```

This is my pure react component. How can I switch to react-redux. I know all the basics of redux. I am not able to figure out the way as the code to change the state (player:player) is inside the componentsDidMount only and we are changing the state by setState method here itself.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot switch a single component to Redux. When you say that you use Redux, it means you use it for the whole app. Actually, you *can* use Redux for a part of your app, just because you can treat that part as a separate module, but it's not the right way.

Redux itself is just a state container. It is stand-alone, it can be used without React. What makes Redux usable with React is a `react-redux` package. I bet you already have it in your project dependencies, but if not, do

```
$ npm install --save redux react-redux
```

Now, you need to connect that component to your Redux workflow. The key word is "connect". To do that, there's a function called `connect` that comes in `react-redux` package. Import it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
```

The [`connect` function accepts up to four arguments](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options). To get started with it, you only need the first one, *a function that maps state to props*. It means that it is executed with the whole Store passed to its first argument, and whatever is returned will appear in your component's props. The result of executing `connect` function is another function that accepts the reference to your component as a reference, and so makes sure your component really will receive these props from that store.

The code:

```
export default connect(state => ({
  // here, you pick the properties of state you want to put into the props of PlayerLogic
}))(PlayerLogic);
```

you can see that `connect(...)(...)` syntax — that's because, again, doing `connect(...)` returns a function, and executing that function (i.e. `connect(...)(...)`) returns a component that is connected to your Store.

You still can maintain component's own state after that, but the whole purpose is to spin off the state management to the single Store you have. If a component updates its state with `this.setState`, to update any value, or many values in the Store, you need to [*dispatch an action*](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html). Since you mentioned that you know Redux basics, I believe you can move on your own from this point. Good luck!